# How to check array items contain a string in php?

Tags: php

I have array like this :

```
$array = ["C","D","D#m","B","A","Am","A#m"];
```

How can I check my array items has this "#"?

Comment: Check and then what?  Count how many? Check just one?  Get index? What?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be faster than a loop.  Just create a string and check:

```
if(strpos(implode($array), '#')  !== false) {
    //yes
}
```

Or with a regex to check for any:

```
if(preg_grep('/#/', $array)) {
    //yes
}
```

To get a count of the items:

```
if(count(preg_grep('/#/', $array)) == 3) {
    //yes
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below snippet of [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to see if it exists '#',

```
foreach($arr as $v){
    if(strpos($v, "#")  !== false){
        // do something
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/8AQLO).